# Cannot find System.Runtime.Remoting.ChannelServices

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-4.8

I have created a c# client application. I am trying to implement a remoting service. I have added the reference to System.Runtime.Remoting(I can see under assembly).
Can someone please help?

Comment: Does issue happen on build machine and core, or only core?  What version of Core do you have installed on deploy machine?

Comment: No support for Remoting in .NETCore and .NET5.